# Image in Node JS Images Folder Not Showing on Site

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to add an image to my `index.ejs` file, but my code is not pulling the image from the `/image` folder specified in my second code block. Can anyone help me find the solution to my issue?

```js
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const { path } = require('express/lib/application');
 const { HTTPRequest } = require('puppeteer');
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';

 app.use('/public/images', express.static('/public/images'));

 //setup connection
 MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true})
 .then(client => {
 console.log('connected to database');
 const db = client.db('user-signup-info');
 const manateeCollection = db.collection('manatees');
 })

 //----------middleware------------
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 //----------routes----------------
 //going to index.ejs and reading database entries
 app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
 db.collection('manatees').find().toArray()
 .then(manatees => {
     res.render('index.ejs', {manatees: manatees})
 })
 .catch(/*....*/)
 })

 //grabbing form data and adding to database
 app.post('/manatees', (req, res)=>{
 //console.log(req.body);
 manateeCollection.insertOne(req.body)
 .then(result =>{
     //console.console.log(result);
     res.redirect('/');
 })
 .catch(error => console.error(error));
 })

 //----------server----------------
 app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('server is running');
 })

 //----------end of connection-----
 .catch(console.error);
```

```html
 <img src="/images/Manatee_CGrant_VisitCitrus-1200x500.jpg">
```

Comment: Your route for serving images is `/public/images` but your EJS file is just using /images. Just a guess but that's probably the issue. A logger like morgan would help identify requests coming in

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your middleware to -
app.use(express.static('public/images'))